# Tkinter clear a message widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a function in which I output a text file's contents to a 'Message' widget in Tkinter. The user selects an option which corresponds to a text file, and presses 'OK'.

The problem I'm having is that I do not know how to clear the message box after selecting two consecutive options.

QUESTION:
How do I clear the message box of the first text, before outputting the second? At the moment the second text outputs over the top of the first.

I have tried Message.delete and Message.clear but I don't think they're applicable to the message widget.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
def learn(event):
    ''' This function creates a new window within the main window, passes an event(left mouse click), and creates a text heading'''
    root = Toplevel(window)

    menu_choice = StringVar(root)
    menu_choice.set("Select") # initial value

    selection_message = Message(root, text = "Choose which area of finances you'd like to learn about below!", width = 180)
    selection_message.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 6)

    menu_options = OptionMenu(root, menu_choice, "Stocks", "Bonds", "Index Funds", "Exchange Traded Funds (ETF's)")
    menu_options.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

    def selection():
        learn_area = menu_choice.get()
        learn_file = open('C:\\Users\\nicks_000\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\SAT\\GUI\\Text Files\\{0}.txt'.format(learn_area))
        learn_text = learn_file.read()
        learn_file.close()

        about_message = Message(root, text = learn_text, width = 300, relief = RAISED)
        about_message.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 6)

    selection_button = Button(root, text="OK", command=selection)
    selection_button.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want but you can change text of [Message widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/message.htm) by `widget_name.configure("text") = "new_text_here"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you created the `about_message` widget inside the selection function, so you recreate one each time you call the function. I suggest you to create the widget outside the selection function so that you can do `about_message.configure(text="new text")`. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def learn():
    ''' This function creates a new window within the main window, passes an event(left mouse click), and creates a text heading'''
    root = Toplevel(window)

    menu_choice = StringVar(root)
    menu_choice.set("Select") # initial value

    selection_message = Message(root, text = "Choose which area of finances you'd like to learn about below!", width = 180)
    selection_message.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 6)

    menu_options = OptionMenu(root, menu_choice, "Stocks", "Bonds", "Index Funds", "Exchange Traded Funds (ETF's)")
    menu_options.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

    def selection():
        learn_area = menu_choice.get()
        learn_file = open('C:\\Users\\nicks_000\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\SAT\\GUI\\Text Files\\{0}.txt'.format(learn_area))
        learn_text = learn_file.read()
        learn_file.close()
        about_message.configure(text=learn_text)  

    selection_button = Button(root, text="OK", command=selection)
    selection_button.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    # create about_message outside the selection function
    # to be able to modify its content
    about_message = Message(root, text = "", width = 300, relief = RAISED)
    about_message.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 6)

Button(window,text="test", command=learn).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had an inkling that that was the case, but I didn't know how to change the text when the message widget was created outside the loop. As in, I was trying things like, 'about_message = about_message(text = learn_text)', but to no avail.